# How to catch input into a variable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically i am trying to create a AJAX script in Jquery.
but the main problem is that i want to define the variables like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var u = $('#username');
    var s = $('#server');
    var p = $('#password');

    $('#server').keyup(function () {
         $.post("connect.php", { s: s.value, u: u.value , p: p.value },
             function(data) {
             $('#hol').html('checking connection...' + u.value + " " + p.value + " " + s.value + " " + data);
                             }
                 ); 
   });

});
```

But that somehow doesn't work.... it seems rather odd that i have to define the variables with "this" instead of being able to assign them before hand.

the code that works is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#username').keyup(function () {
        var u = this;
            $('#password').keyup(function () {
            var p = this;
                   $('#server').keyup(function () {
                    var s = this;

                     $.post("connect.php", { s: s.value, u: u.value , p: p.value },
                     function(data) {
                        $('#hol').html('checking connection...' + u.value + " " + p.value + " " + s.value + " " + data);
                                         }); });
                 }); 
                  }); 
   });
```

so my question is basically "How do I make jquery catch the input in the text field and assign it to a variable? like in the first example??" or it doesnt have to be done in the long way?

Comment: Sending AJAX requests onkeyup is a bad idea. Add some debouncing code so it only happens if the user stops typing for some time (250ms might be good).

Comment: Shouldn't the selector for your first code block be `$('#server, #username, #password')`

Comment: The "code that works" doesn't really work: nesting keyup handler creation means if the user enters their password first for some reason then the #server keyup never gets set and the Ajax call doesn't happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.value`:

```
{ s: s.val(), u: u.val() , p: p.val() }
```

as `s`,`u`,and `p` are jQuery objects, not DOM Elements.

Comment: @JohnP Yes, but in that case, you will lose "magical" jQuery functionalities on `s`,`u` and `p` elements ).

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val();`

```
var u = $('#username').val();
var s = $('#server').val();
var p = $('#password').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

as an *alternative* you can use [**`serialize()`**](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission

```
$('#server').keyup(function () {
         $.post("connect.php", $('input[type=text]').serialize(),
             function(data) {
             $('#hol').html('checking connection ' + data);
         }); 
   });
```

Comment: But you've still got u.value, p.value and s.value which was the problem in the original code..

Answer (score 0):

you can use in this manner

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var u = $('#username');
    var s = $('#server');
    var p = $('#password');

    s.keyup(function () {
         $.post("connect.php", { s: s.val(), u: u.val() , p: p.val() },
             function(data) {
             $('#hol').html('checking connection...' + u.val() + " " + p.val() + " " + s.val() + " " + data);
                             }
                 ); 
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery selectors..

```
var u = $('#username');
var s = $('#server');
var p = $('#password');
```

and accessing values in `javascript` fashion....

```
u.value; //WRONG
```

if you are using `jQuery` then the right way is

```
u.val();
```

or

```
u.attr('value');
```

Same goes for v and w :)

Comment: _"and accessing values in javascript fashion"_ - should be "accessing values in DOM element fashion". Every part of the OP's code including jQuery "syntax" _is_ JavaScript, but the problem is `.value` is a DOM element property not a jQuery object property.

Answer (score 0):

This should cover everything:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var u = $('#username'),
      s = $('#server'),
      p = $('#password');

  function doYourAjaxCall() {
    $.post("connect.php", { 
      s: s.val(), 
      u: u.val(), 
      p: p.val() 
    },
    function(data) {
      $('#hol').html('checking connection...' + u.val() + " " + p.val() + " " + s.val() + " " + data);
    });
  }

  u.keyup(doYourAjaxCall);
  s.keyup(doYourAjaxCall);
  p.keyup(doYourAjaxCall);

});
```

As always, I'd recommend reading [How Good C# Habits can Encourage Bad JavaScript Habits](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/)